# Depth Buffer not being written to by Draw calls

Tags: c++, direct3d, direct3d11, dxut

I've had zero luck getting depth buffering working.  Everything renders, but only in the order I layer them.  When I look at the depth stencil in the VS Graphics Debugger, it is NEVER written to.  It should be, from everything I can think of, but it remains all red in the debugger (which just means it's still clear).

Both the rendertarget and the depthstencil are created for me by DXUT, and I've inspected them closely enough to be fairly certain they all look good.  I've walked its creation code and had MSDN open and checked every flag - but thousands have used that code before, I suspect the DXUT end is fine.

My rendertarget is a Texture2D, R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB, 1280x1024, Sample count 1, Quality 0, Mip levels 1, set to bind to render target, no flags.

My depthstencil is a Texture2D, D24_UNORM_S8_UINT, 1280x1024, Sample count 1, Quality 0, Mip levels 1, set to bind as depth stencil, no other flags.

At the beginning of my render, I clear the rendertargetview.  Hard to mess that up.  Next I clear the DepthStencil:

```
pd3dImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView(DXUTGetD3D11RenderTargetView(), Colors::Black);
pd3dImmediateContext->ClearDepthStencilView(DXUTGetD3D11DepthStencilView(), D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);
```

My depth stencil state for ALL draws is:

```
DepthEnable      TRUE
DepthFunc        LESS_EQUAL
DepthWriteMask   ALL
StencilEnable    FALSE
```

The DepthStencilView shows up as

```
Texture2D, D24_UNORM_S8_UINT, no flags, MipSlice 0
```

in the VS Graphics debugger.  I have blending set to solid.

It does not look like a mismatch (for example, multisampling) on the rendertarget texture vs the depthstencil texture, as I've confirmed (unless those two DXGI formats are for some reason incompatible).

Everything looks right other than depth, so I'm going to presume my transformation matrices are all fine.

The only other hint I have at this point is that if I clear the depth buffer with 0.999999, everything disappears.  With 1.0, everything draws (though with incorrect/absent depth).

The viewport is set to window size, then 0.0 as min depth and 1.0 as max.  That's the first thing I checked.

My rasterizer state is:

```
FillMode SOLID 
CullMode BACK 
FrontCounterClockwise FALSE 
DepthBias 0 
DepthBiasClamp 0.000f 
SlopeScaleDepthBias 0.000f 
DepthClipEnable TRUE 
ScissorEnable FALSE 
MultisampleEnable TRUE 
AntialiasedLineEnable FALSE
```

ForcedSampleCount 0

If there's nothing blatantly wrong above, what's the next logical thing to check?  Given I'm using the DXUT framework, I'm not doing a lot of the creation plumbing on my own and it's always worked before!  And in the debugger, it all looks great.

The only thing I can't check are the outputs of the vertex shader because the graphics debugger explodes and crashes.

Comment: Are you rendering things with different depths, or is your transform projecting all your objects into a flat plane (so that everything has the same depth)?

Comment: Any chance to see the vertex shader code? and eventually the projection matrix setup (just in case there's something simple with near/far planes)?